# Laravel - How to set all is status to 0 when the current one is 1

Tags: laravel

I have this code in my Laravel 5.8 controller:

```
public function store(StoreIdentityRequest $request)
{
        $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;

        $identity = Identity::create([
            'name'                 => $request->name,
            'is_status'            => $request->has('is_status'),
        ]);    
        $id = $identity->id;
        
        Identity::where('id', '!=', $id)
            ->where('company_id', $userCompany)
            ->update(['is_current' => 0]);
}
```

`is_status` can either be 0 or 1.

When user submits, if the current (or selected) `is_status` is 1, I expect the application to toggle all other `is_status` values to 0 except the current one.

I applied this code as shown in the controller:

```
Identity::where('id', '!=', $id)
    ->where('company_id', $userCompany)
    ->update(['is_current' => 0]);
```

but it turns everything to 0 even when the current `is_status` is 0

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I'm reading this over and over again and have trouble understanding the context. `Identity` seems to belong to a `Company` you say * if the current (or selected)*. How do you differentiate? In general can you try to provide more detail or the bigger picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing all good just do is_current = 0 first, then make your new entry with is_current = 1 : something like this

```
    public function store(StoreIdentityRequest $request)
    {
            $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
     if($request->is_status == 0){
      Identity::where('company_id', $userCompany)->update(['is_status'=>0]);
    }
            $identity = Identity::create([
                'name'                 => $request->name,
              'is_status'            => $request->is_status,
            ]);    
           
    }
```